# Python : Formatting issue with Groupby

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to groupby on salary column to get frequency of each salary category as below :

```
def PROC_FREQ(dataset,arg1):

        x= dataset.groupby(arg1)[arg1[-1]].agg(({'Frequency':'count'}))


        print('\n')
        print(x)
        print('\n')

PROC_FREQ(df,['SAL'])
```

But it is giving below output where SAL and FREQUENCY headers are not propery aligned:

```
     Frequency
SAL           
100          2
200          1
300          1
```

I want output like below so that SAL and FREQUENCY headers should be properly to aligned to each other:

```
SAL     Frequency           
100          2
200          1
300          1
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use reset_index

your df looks like this,

```
       Frequency
SAL        
100       2
200       1
300       1


df=df.reset_index()
print(df)        
SAL     Frequency      
100          2
200          1
300          1
```